# Does PHP create output buffer for anonymous function?

Tags: php

I wonder what happens in the following code:

```
<?php
function CountUp($count2, $count1)
{
    $count1(); // Say one
    $count2(); // Say two
}

CountUp(function() {
?>
    Two
<?php
}, function() {
?>
    One
<?
});
```

Apparently PHP creates an output buffer for the anonymous functions and flushes that buffer when we call them.

The question is: is that expected PHP behavior? I would like to use this feature in my template engine so it must not be hackish and have unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Using anonymous functions in PHP, the way you are doing, will always be hackish. BTW: this is expected behaviour, because a lambda function creates a new instance of the Lambda object...

Comment: i don't think a buffer is being created, it just isn't evaluating the text outside of the PHP tags until the anonymous function is called

Comment: `?> ... <?php` is equivalent to `echo "...";`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function x() {
   echo 'x';
}
x();
?>
```

is functionally identical to

```
<?php function y() { ?>
y
<? } 
y();

?>
```

Both will output their `x` and `y` chars only when the function is called.

Comment: He wants to use it in a template engine. So i really don't think this is "functionally identical".